# Thank You Mailing for Permissioned Relationship after Renewal

Tags: civicontribute, renewals

I'm trying to setup a scheduled reminder to send a Thank You message after a membership is renewed. **Note that this is for organisation memberships**

I only want this message to go to the permissioned primary contact that logs in and renews the membership.

I know that I can use the Membership entity in scheduled reminders to send the Thank You message for new members using the **Membership join date option**. This correctly send the Thank You message to the permissioned primary contact.

However, I don't have an option when using the Membership entity to configure it to send the messsage after a membership is renewed.

I can use the activity entity but that would send the thank you message to all the related employees and not just the permissioned employee.

Does anyone have any workarounds for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Rebecca, try creating a smart group based on your condition for choosing recipients. Use Membership Renewal activity for sending reminders ad limit the recipients to 'select group'.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try creating a smart group for primary members only and then limit the recipients for the selected scheduled reminder to that group.

Comment: Hi Rebecca,
I'm using the Membership Renewal activity as the trigger.

When I'm using activities, I do not get the option to limit to a group.

Answer (score 0):

The Email API extension has an action to send an email to a related contact.  Provided that your primary contact has a different relationship type than the others, you could use CiviRules + Email API to send the email.